# error code vs error condition

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't quite get why do we need to make a distinction between error code `(std::error_code)` and an error `condition(std::error_condition)`, aren't they the same thing? What are the advantages of an error condition vs error code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_condition

> `std::error_condition` is a platform-independent error code. Like
> `std::error_code`, it is uniquely identified by an integer value and a
> `std::error_category`, but unlike `std::error_code`, the value is not
> platform-dependent.

So, the advantage is your error code isn't specific to the platform you're working on when using `std::error_condition`.

With an `std::error_code`

> Each `std::error_code` object holds a pair of error code originating
> from the operating system, or some low-level interface

So, the `error_code` will reference something specific to your platform, a piece of hardware etc etc.

It may be advantageous to use both. The `error_condition` is the "portable abstraction" so would be the generic error message to give to the user and the `error_code` would be the platform dependent information that would be useful for specific debug.

> A typical implementation [of `error_condition`] holds one integer data member (the value) and
> a pointer to an `std::error_category`.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest answer to this question I found here: http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-5.html.

> - class `std::error_code` - represents a specific error value returned by an operation (such as a system call).
> - class `std::error_condition` - something that you want to test for and, potentially, react to in your code.

I think it is applicable for C++11 too.

Comment: So if I have a few custom categories and corresponding error enums for each category, and all of that is consistent across all my platforms, should I return `std::error_code`s  (in that I have specific values from my operations) or `std::error_condition` in that my error values and conditions are platform-independent?

Answer (score 7):

Good naming has a huge impact on understanding. With the zoo of very similarly named errorish things introduced in C++11...

```
std::errc            - an error code
std::error_code      - a different error code?
std::error_condition - yet another kind of error code 
std::error_category  - a utility helper interface for error codes
```

...I had to make a mental map just to sort them all out:

```
std::errc              -> std::posix_error_code
std::error_code        -> std::platform_dependent_error
std::error_condition   -> std::platform_independent_error
std::error_category    -> std::error_domain/utility/mapper
std::system_category   -> std::platform_dependent_error_domain
std::generic_category  -> std::platform_independent_error_domain
std::future_errc       -> std::future_error_code
std::future_category   -> std::future_error_domain
std::io_errc           -> std::iostream_error_code
std::iostream_category -> std::iostream_error_domain
```

Both [platform-dependent errors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code) and [platform-independent errors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_condition) hold a code and a pointer to a [utility helper class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_category) to map that domain-specific error codes to a [message](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_category/message). Despite having nearly identical interfaces {assign, clear, value, message...}, they don't inherit from a common base class, meaning you can't generically call one or the other's methods. ‍♂️

Observe that [`std::error_code`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code) is not an error code, but rather a combo of error code + plus domain/category, whereas `std::errc` is an *actual* error code (a numeric value). Good ideas - awful naming .