# Use cases for std::error_code

Tags: c++, c++11, error-code

Lately I've been converting some libraries to use the `<system_error>` facilities in C++11.

I'm having difficulty understanding the use cases for `std::error_code` vs. `std::error_condition`.

Note, **I understand the difference** - there are [many questions on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687403/error-code-vs-error-condition) which go over the difference.

The basic difference is that `std::error_code` is supposed to represent a system- or platform-specific error, whereas `std::error_condition` is an abstract error that an API or user interface should return.

Okay - but I'm having trouble understanding why we would ever use `std::error_code` in practice.  It seems to me you're either going to :

1. Be dealing with a system specific error reporting mechanism (like
   say, `errno` or something returned from a POSIX call, or say, a call
   to `getsockopt` with `SO_ERROR` on Linux) which you can easily
   convert to an `std::error_condition` via the `std::errc` enums, which are supposed to be portable.
2. Be using a user-defined category of errors, which represent application-level
   or business-logic errors, like "invalid social security number" or
   whatever - which also would be a use case for
   `std::error_condition`.
3. Be dealing with some low-level interface or library which defines its own error reporting mechanism, such as OpenSSL, in which case you would be directly using platform-specific error mechanisms.  In this case you'd then need to convert or map these errors to an `std::error_code`.  But if you're going to go through the trouble of converting these platform specific errors to something generic like `std::error_code`, why not just convert to `std::error_condition`?

Also, since POSIX system errors are supposed to be portable, and since they map one-to-one with `std::error_condition` via the `std::errc` enum, I can't find any use case for `std::error_code`.  Most Linux/UNIX system calls set `errno`, which is supposed to portably map to `std::error_condition`.

So, I don't see any use case for `std::error_code` anywhere.  So, what are some example use cases where we would want to use `std::error_code` instead of `std::error_condition`?

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16687434/560648) is not clear?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, the idea is clear - but I don't see the use of `error_code` in practice.  The link you provided says: "Each `std::error_code` object holds a pair of error code originating from the operating system, or some low-level interface" - okay, but the operating system will either give you a POSIX error (which is portable and can be converted to `std::error_condition` easily) or some other type of low-level error (like I guess a Win32 error, for example), which you'd then need to manually map to `std::error_code` - but what is the use of mapping it to error_code? ...

Comment: ... if you need to do something platform specific, you work directly with the platform facilities.  If you need to convert the error to something more generic, you use error_condition.  I just don't see how error_code fits in to any of this.

Comment: That answer gives you a use case "in practice". _"The error_condition is the "portable abstraction" so would be the generic error message to give to the user and the error_code would be the platform dependent information that would be useful for specific debug."_ I honestly don't get the problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm just dense, but I'm just not getting it. "The error_code would be the platform dependent information that would be useful for specific debug" ???     To me the use of `error_code` just sounds redundant here.  The actual platform dependent information *itself* is what would be useful for a specific debug.  Why go through the extra step of converting to error_code if you're not dealing in abstractions?

Comment: Because there's a common type giving you a stable interface across all variants of your product? It's still an abstraction.

Comment: But for the actual *interface* (like the API) aren't we supposed to be dealing in `std::error_condition`s?

Comment: error_code --> there is an error , 
error_condition --> what can we do about it

Comment: Unlike you i can't see why to ever use "error_condition". given the fact that terrible little thoughts went into the design of error condtions (they really took just unix codes). There is no mapping for many real life error conditions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I was wondering about that a while back myself and found the answer [here](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-5.html).  Essentially, `error_code` is used to store and transport error codes, while `error_condition` is used to match error codes.

```
void handle_error(error_code code) {
   if     (code == error_condition1) do_something();
   else if(code == error_condition2) do_something_else();
   else                              do_yet_another_thing();
}
```

Each `error_condition` is equivalent to a set of `error_code`, possibly from different `error_categories`.  This way you can treat all errors of a certain type the same, no matter which subsystem they originate from.

`error_code` on the other hand contains exactly the category of the subsystem it originated from.  This is useful for debugging and when reporting the error: you may be interested to know whether a "permission denied" error was because of insufficient access rights on the local file system or because of a 403 error that your http-downloader-library received, and may want to put that detail in the error message, but your program has to abort either way.

What constitutes equivalence is defined by the categories; if the `error_code`'s category considers the `error_condition` equivalent, **or** the `error_condition`'s category considers the `error_code` equivalent, then `operator==` returns `true` for that pair of `error_condition` and `error_code`.  That way you can have `error_code`s from your own error category and make them equivalent to certain generic or system `error_condition`s.

Comment: I'd clarify that a library should signal errors with `error_code`s and declare or reuse standard `error_condition` enums for matching them. This way full information about an error is passed around and a user of such a library can print it to the log or so. But extra details are hidden from upper program logic.

Comment: Agree with explanation.  This also suggests APIs should prefer to propagate `error_code` as the non-lossy actual error-value, where code testing results of an operation should cause implicit conversion to `error_condition` where additional categories might be defined to collapse-and-convert system-specific error-values to platform-independent failure scenarios.